# Workflow Rule for status change won't trigger the timestamp field during approval process

Tags: workflow, field-update

I've a workflow rule which updates a timestamp field (date/time) when ever a case status changes from one status to another. It's working fine when I test it by manually changing the status of a case. The case involves an approval process and when a case is approved, it updates the status. The workflow rule however, won't trigger the field update when the status is changed through the approval process. **I've even enabled the re-evaluate workflow rules as well but still wouldn't work.** Any help guys?

Here's my formula used in WFR:

```
ISChanged(Status) && ISPICKVAL(Status,'Waiting for Dept. Assignment')
&& ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status),'Waiting Level 1 Approval')
```

When status changes from Waiting Level 1 Approval to Waiting for Dept. Assignment (through approval process), I want a field update on timestamp field.

Comment: is this timestamp field on case object or a different object?

Comment: It's on the case object.

Comment: Any help people?